# Excel hyperlink requires unnecessary additional login

Tags: excel, google-chrome, url, hyperlink

I created an excel hyperlink using something like the following: =HYPERLINK("https://abc.com/"&A1)

When I click on it, it opens up a new tab in Chrome asking me to login (the page has sensitive information and requires user authentication), even though I'm already logged in previously.

However, if I were to copy from the cell and paste it directly in the url bar in Chrome it automatically brings me to the page without logging in again.

Is there a way to sidestep this issue?

Answer (score 0):

See [Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317352/bharath)'s answer to a similar question here:
[Excel Hyperlinks redirecting to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376388/excel-links-not-loading-pages-but-when-the-link-is-pasted-in-%20the-browser-it-wor?rq=1)

> 1. Create a redirect.html page in your public folder (public folder because you are using ROR)
> 2. Copy this to your redirect.html

```
 <html>
 <body>
 Please wait, loading your page... 
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function getQuerystring(key) {
         key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/    [\]]/,"\\\]");
         var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
         var query = regex.exec(window.location.href);
         return query[1];
     }
     window.location = "http://" + window.location.host + "/" + getQuerystring('page');
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

> The links you are constructing in excel should be modified
>
> For e.g Old link - `http://test.com/post/comments/1` New link should be
>   - `http://test.com/redirect.html?page=post/comments/1`
>
> You need to pass the part of URL (after base url) as a param How this
>   works.
>
> When user clicks a link in excel it points to redirect.html and the
>   javascript constructs the actual URL and redirects again to proper
>   page, user will be navigated to actual page if already logged in else
>   redirected to Login/Home page.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, I have just added.

Comment: I had the same problem, so I implemented something similar on my server. I'm including a google sheet with an example and the source code in php / javascript. Here's the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n57gPAShPc58X-zROzAypX-fGA8_YJb3TaAKCVPFxJU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For an updated redirect.html, with Web APIs instead of regexes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969243/685715